# Как лучше передать переменные в другой класс?

Tags: java, android, adapter

В своем приложении я использую адаптер для gridview и listener для адаптера, в котором передаю 7 переменных, так как они мне нужны в классе адаптера. Абсолютно все переменные мне нужны в классе адаптера, последние 5 относятся к одному объекту.

Хороший ли это способ для эффектиновсти - передавать 7 значений через параметры за раз? Если нет, то каким способом можно передать последние 5 переменных? Можно ли передавать вместо этих переменных объект класса, который будет хранить переменные или это не будет влиять на работоспособность?
Как я передаю переменные для адаптера:

```
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, y, m, d, habitId, s);
              
            }
        });
```

Comment: по логике можно передать объект класса и все, а дальше уже разобрать его по полям просто

Comment: и передача такого количества переменных через объект класса  не скажется на роботоспособности?

Comment: что подразумевается над работоспособностью?

Comment: Количество параметров в конструкторе так влияет на работоспособность в целом, что этот фактор можно совершенно не учитывать.

Comment: То-есть я могу передавать хоть 100 параметров и количество ошибок не увеличиться?

Comment: Если вы сможете все эти параметры не перепутать, то конечно не увеличится. Рекомендуется избегать большого количества параметров в конструкторе не потому, что компилятор может с этим не справиться, а именно из за появляющихся сложностей с сопровождением и поддержкой кода (человеческий фактор). Если классу требуется много параметров имеет смысл рассмотреть шаблон builder, но сначала убедится, что класс соответствует принципам SOLID